# Why is there an 'it' in "I find it very difficult to do this"?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

I find it strange that one has to use the pronoun *it* in sentences like

> I find *it* very difficult to do this.

I would like to know the grammatical reason (if there is one) for this, if it has name, and how bad it is if you omit it.

Comment: The pronoun could be eliminated in this example by saying "I find doing this very difficult".

Comment: Shouldn't your sentence start like 'English being..' instead of 'Being English..'?

Comment: Many of your assumptions are wrong; "Being English a fairly economical language" is ungrammatical; there is double negation of several kinds in English; many English words are quite long and the short words all have many different meanings and idioms. As for the grammar of this particular sentence, it is a reduced infinitive complement that has undergone: 1) Extraposition (this is where the _it_ comes from; it's just a dummy to keep the subject slot); 2) B-Raising (which moves this _it_ up to become the object of _find_; 3) _to-be_-Deletion. (2) and (3) are governed by _find_.

Comment: I edited the question a little bit. Thanks to Ramit and John Lawler for the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Find* in this meaning is transitive. It needs an object, plain and simple. You cannot just find difficult. You can only find *something/someone* difficult.

In the particular case of *find* it is actually quite logical that it would need an object. But generally speaking, there is no why. Some verbs are transitive and others are not. There is not always an intrinsic reason for them to be the way they are. As demonstrated by the fact that the exact same verbs in the exact same meaning can be transitive in one language but intransitive in another.

Comment: I see that _find_ is a transitive verb, but it seems somewhat redundant to introduce _it_ when I could regard "to do this" as the object of the sentence. Could I just say "I find very difficult to do this"?

Comment: "To do this" is a verb phrase. For the object you need a noun, or something that actions like one: a pronoun or a gerund. So "I find doing this (to be) very difficult" is perfectly fine. But "I find to do this (to be) very difficult" is not.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It was the piece of information that I needed.

Answer (score 0):

There's a similar usage in "It is raining", "It is cold", "It looks like we're going to have to leave".

The "it" takes the place of "I find doing this very difficult"; "it" is a "placeholder" that points ahead to "this".

In my first two examples, what is it that is raining?  Could we say "The sky is raining", or "The clouds are raining"?  Or even "The weather is raining"?  All of these seem convoluted.  "It's raining" might even be called an idiom.

A possible alternative might be "Rain is happening", or for your example, "I've found that doing this is very difficult".  The "it construction" simplifies the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

The mix-up seems to be caused by "this" at the end of the sentence.
Find is a transitive verb and as such needs an object. Therefore "it" (e.g playing basketball/getting up early/task/action) takes on this role."this" (in our case probably referring to an action or task) is playing no role whatsoever.The object of find has already been defined.
The sentence,therefore, could quite simply be written as:
I find it very difficult to do OR I find this very difficult to do.